# Not support hover function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

Mouse function cannot be support

```
$("div.container1:has('#image')").hover(function() {
        console.log("Success hover");
 });
```

and this is my div class

```
<div class="container1">
  <img src="img/1920/blue.jpg" id="imageId"/>
 </div>
```

functionality in div class for click action

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        var img = $('<button>');
        img.css('top', y);
        img.css('left', x);
        img.css('position', 'absolute');
        img.attr('type', 'button');
        img.attr('id', 'image');
        img.css('z-index', 1);
        img.attr('class', 'btn btn-info btn-lg');
        $(this).attr('data-toggle','modal');
        $(this).attr('data-target','#myModal');
        img.attr('data-toggle','modal');
        img.attr('data-target','#myModal');
        console.log("Mouse action Start");
        img.appendTo('.container1');
        /*$(this).removeClass('.container1');*/
        console.log("Mouse action End");
        $(this).removeClass('<button>'); 


    });


});
```

Comment: can you make it more clear , what exact problem you are facing ?

Comment: I have background Image. I try with hotspot type.so right now  i have lot of button and one background image .I need button hover function

Answer (score 0):

It is because .hover takes two parameters. A callback for when the mouseenters, and a callback for when it leaves.

Also, are you adding the DOM element and THEN adding the click handler? If so, you definitely need to use `.on()`.

.on() is used for elements that are added dynamically to the DOM.
you probably need to do `.on('mouseenter', [callback])` AND `.on('mouseleave', [callback])` rather than `.hover()`. just fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of selecting works , [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kalaganire/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
 $("div.container1 #imageId").hover(function() {
            console.log("Success hover");
  });
```

Comment: I also try but cannot be response